# How to start a new activity by sliding it over the previous one?

Tags: android

I want to have an animation effect similar to unlocking a phone(sliding the screen upwards to reveal content below it) while starting a new activity.

[image]

Is this even possible between activities?
How can this design be implemented?

Comment: You really should be using fragments rather than new activites for this

Comment: @NarendraKothamire I dont know whether it is even possible to do such an animation so no progress as of now.

Comment: @ruffles How will i do this using fragments? even different layout in the same activity will work

Answer (score 3):

create a folder named anim in your res folder and copy the below xml files to anim folder.

pull_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

push_out_righ.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

And add below code to your second activities onCreate()

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right,
                    R.anim.push_out_left);
```

Comment: The animation is not sliding over the activity. Its pushing the activity aside.

Comment: Replace all X axis to Y axis and adjust the duration

Comment: It will just push the activity from Y Axis. The new activity won't slide over the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity which override those 2 methods:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_slide_in_right, R.anim.animation_slide_out_left);
}


public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_slide_in_left, R.anim.animation_slide_out_right);
}
```

Any activities which want to have the slide animation need to extend this class.

animation_slide_in_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

animation_slide_out_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

animation_slide_in_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

animation_slide_out_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```